# How does the product of two polynomials from different rings of polynomials make sense?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

I have asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3186016/confusion-about-a-ring-homomorphism-theorem-in-textbook-analysis-i-by-amann-esch) and gave a comment regarding an answer by Captain Lama. He seems to be busy or not interested in my question any more that he has not responded to my comment, so I have no choice but to post another related question in this thread.

I think it is not good to copy relevant concept/information (which I typed carefully) from that question to this one. The copying will make this thread unnecessarily long. If you are interested in answering this question, please take a look at the old one.

---

My textbook states that

> $p=\sum_{\alpha} p_{\alpha} X^{\alpha} \in  K\left[X_{1}, \ldots, X_{m}\right]$ can be written in the form $p=\sum_{j=0}^{n} q_{j} X_{m}^{j}$ for suitable $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $q_{j} \in K\left[X_{1}, \dots, X_{m-1}\right]$.

From Captain Lama's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3189316/368425), I got that $X^j_m \in K[X_1,\dots,X_m]$ and $q_j \in K[X_1,\cdots,X_{m-1}]$.

My question: $K[X_1,\dots,X_m] \neq K[X_1,\cdots,X_{m-1}]$ and thus they are two different rings of polynomials. How can the product $q_{j} X_{m}^{j}$ make sense?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: One of the rings is a subring of the other.

Comment: @RolfHoyer In my textbook, *a formal power series in $m$ indeterminates over $K$* is a function from $\Bbb N^m$ to $K$. Please check if I understand your ideas correctly. By *One of the rings is a subring of the other*, you meant that $K[X_1,\dots,X_{m-1}]$ is not a subset $K[X_1,\cdots,X_m]$ and that there is a ring-isomorphism $f:K[X_1,\dots,X_{m-1}] \to K[X_1,\cdots,X_m]$. You meant that $q_{j} X_{m}^{j}$ denotes the product of $f(q_j) \in K[X_1,\dots,X_m]$ and $X_{m}^{j} \in K[X_1,\dots,X_m]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that the polynomial $p \in K[X_1, \ldots, X_m]$ is being written as a polynomial in the one variable $X_m$, whose coefficients are polynomials in $K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m-1}]$.  So $q_j X_m^j$ is not a product of elements of different rings, but rather a coefficient $q_j$ times a variable $X_m$ raised to a power, and a polynomial ring can have coefficients in any ring.  So the fact that we can make polynomials of the form $\sum_{j = 1}^{n} q_j X_m^j$ makes sense for the same reason that it makes sense to consider polynomials with coefficients in say, the integers, or any arbitrary ring.

In other words, what this lemma is saying is we can write $K[X_1, \ldots, X_m]$ as $K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m - 1}][X_{m}]$, or more succinctly as $R[X_m]$, where $R$ is the ring $K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m - 1}]$.

Comment: Did you meant by *we can write $K[X_1, \ldots, X_m]$ as $K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m - 1}][X_{m}]$* that $K[X_1, \ldots, X_m] = K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m - 1}][X_{m}]$, or just there is an isomorphism between $K[X_1, \ldots, X_m]$ and $K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m - 1}][X_{m}]$?

Comment: There is a canonical isomorphism between them.  The question of being "equal" is a little more subtle.  Technically the first is the polynomials in $m$ variables over a field, and the second is the polynomials in one variable over a ring, so they aren't "exactly" the same thing

Comment: Please correct me If I'm wrong. I think that $p=\sum_{\alpha} p_{\alpha} X^{\alpha} \neq p' = \sum_{j=0}^{n} q_{j} X_{m}^{j}$. By *$p=\sum_{\alpha} p_{\alpha} X^{\alpha} \in K\left[X_{1}, \ldots, X_{m}\right]$ can be written in the form $p=\sum_{j=0}^{n} q_{j} X_{m}^{j}$ for suitable $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $q_{j} \in K\left[X_{1}, \ldots, X_{m-1}\right]$*, the authors mean that there is a canonical isomorphism between $K[X_1, \ldots, X_m]$ and $K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m - 1}][X_{m}]$.

Comment: This is correct

Comment: Thank you so much for your dedicated help ;)